# InDesign CS5 Script: How do I use BridgeTalk to save new images from Photoshop?

Tags: ajax, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

This script is attempting to:

- create a new folder
- scan an InDesign document for all images
- convert all images to grayscale in Photoshop
- save new grayscale images in the new folder from Photoshop

Converting the images to grayscale in Photoshop requires the use of the `BridgeTalk` object, which allows for the communication between InDesign and Photoshop (the usage of the `BridgeTalk` object seems to be a form of Ajax).

What I have so far is *almost* working, being that a new folder is created, and InDesign does seem to be communicating with Photoshop via `BridgeTalk`. But when Photoshop is opened, nothing happens -- no new images are saved, and I'm not sure if the grayscale conversion is taking place or not...

Here is my code:

```
#target "InDesign"

var inDesignDocument = app.activeDocument;
var newFolder = createFolder(inDesignDocument); // if subdirectory images DNE, create this folder with the function below

sendImagesToPhotoshop(inDesignDocument, newFolder);

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function createFolder(doc)
{
    try
    {
    /*
         * type-casting the filePath property (of type object) into a String type;
         * must be a String type to concatenate with the subdirectory variable (also of type String)
         */
        var docPath = String(doc.filePath);
        var subdirectory = "/BLACK AND WHITE IMAGES";
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
        exit();
    }

    var imagesFolder = docPath + subdirectory; // concatenating the two variables
    if(!Folder(imagesFolder).exists)
    {
        Folder(imagesFolder).create();
    }

    return imagesFolder; // for instantiation outside of this function

} // end of function createFolder

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function sendImagesToPhotoshop(doc, folder)
{
    var imgs = doc.allGraphics;
    var fileName = "";
    var img = "";
    var imgType = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
    {
        if(imgs[i].itemLink != null)
        {
            fileName = imgs[i].itemLink.name;
            img = new File(folder + "/" + fileName); // each image instantiated here
            imgType = imgs[i].imageTypeName; // image type is determined here (.tif, .jpg, .png, etc..)

            alert("The file \"" + fileName + "\"\n\tis a " + imgType + " file.");

            // each image exported to the new folder here, by file type
            switch(imgType)
            {
                case "GIF":
                    alert("This script cannot convert and export the GIF file:\n\t" + fileName + " !");
                    break;

            case "JPG":
            case "EPS":
                case "PNG":
                case "TIFF":

            createBridgeTalkMessage(folder);
                    break;

                default:
                    alert("\tUnlisted image type: " + imgType + "!\nAdd this type to the switch statement.");
                    break;

            } // end of switch statement

        } // end of if statement
    } // end of for loop

} // end of function sendImagesToPhotoshop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function createBridgeTalkMessage(imagesFolder)
{
    var bt = new BridgeTalk();
    bt.target = "photoshop";
    bt.body = saveNewImageInPhotoshop.toSource() + "(" + imagesFolder.toSource() + ");";

    bt.onError = function(e)
    {
        alert("Error: " + e.body);
    }

    bt.onResult = function(resObj){};

    bt.send();

}// end of function createBridgeTalkMessage

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // called from function createBridgeTalkMessage
    function saveNewImageInPhotoshop(imagePath)
    {
        var photoshopDoc = "";
        app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // Photoshop statement, prevents status alerts from interrupting
        photoshopDoc.changeMode(ChangeMode.GRAYSCALE); // convert image to GRAYSCALE

        photoshopDoc.saveAs(new File(imagePath) );
        photoshopDoc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

    } // end of function saveNewImageInPhotoshop
```

This is based on the work of Kasyan Servetsky, found here:  http://forums.adobe.com/message/3817782

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are passing a folder to Photoshop instead of an actual image file. That may probably explain your issue ;)

Loic

Comment: Ha, oops! Ok, so now I am passing the `File` object `img` to BridgeTalk, thanks for pointing that out @Loic.

Comment: However there are other problems, which I have found solutions to -- the function that `bt.body` is calling **can't** have any single-line quotes because `.toSource()` evaluates the entire function and parameters as a single-line String (use multi-line comments instead). Also, the parameter(s) passed to BridgeTalk **must** be of type `File` or `Folder`, because otherwise `.toSource()` is escaping all of the backslashes in the parameter's file path, causing it to not evaluate on `open` or `saveAs`. These are the changes that I made to Servetsky's code (mentioned above) for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I experienced issues recently with single line comments and indeed using /* ... */ did the trick. I think you can pass a string for your url but need to escape the slashes characters.